# i wanted to make arr[0][0] appear largest to smallest but while running it shows the type error arr[i].sort(); is not a function

Tags: javascript

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {

    var largestNumArray = [];
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr = arr[i].sort(function(a, b) {
            return b - a;
        }); 
    }
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Where am I wrong and could you explain about it.

Comment: What is the expected output and why?

Comment: i wanted to get new array of a largest number from each array.Actually it was a challange i have to complete it. i kind a understand array iteration but i get confused in using array iteration results. Actually you can say i kind a cannot play with the array results. I hope you got it .

Answer (score 3):

> while running it shows the type error arr[i].sort(); is not a
>   function.

You are mutating the `arr` by assigning the result of `arr[i].sort()` to `arr`

Make it

```
arr[i]=arr[i].sort(function(a,b){
   return b-a;
});
```

**Edit**

`sort` function mutates the array by itself, so no reason to store it back to `arr[i]` anyways.

```
arr[i].sort(function(a,b){
   return b-a;
});
```

Comment: Just a side note, `sort` modifies the array in place so you don't have to reassign it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-mutating version:

```
const largestOfFour = arr => arr.map(four => four.slice(0).sort((a, b) => a - b))

const foo = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]

largestOfFour(foo);
       //=> [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 18, 26, 27], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1, 857, 1000, 1001]]
       // but foo is unchanged
```

Using `map` together with `slice(0)`, we can avoid mutation.